# But did he gave the cover?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

You wouldn't call your friends the way he's called,
Yet you envy him in his lab.
He maybe had many various jobs,
But purple isn't a good sign for him.
he's the shepherd of us all, from weaks to heroes,
Even if he is just a detestable servant.

Who is the amazing human being in that riddle?

Hint

> I'm looking for an actor!

Hint:

> he's a good friend of Quentin

Comment: Is the fact that you wrote "beeing" rather than "being" deliberate?

Comment: Ditto for "sheperd" versus "shepherd", though that one seems more likely just a typo.

Comment: No, i'm just not so good in english, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This amazing human being is...

> Samuel L. Jackson

You wouldn't call your friends the way he's called,

> This might have something to do with the fact that he's nearly always referenced with his full name including a middle initial, while you would typically not spend so much time with your friends' names.

Yet you envy him in his lab.

> Possibly a reference to his part in Deep Blue Sea, which takes place in a sea lab, or as chief engineer in the Jurassic Park computer lab.

He maybe had many various jobs,

> This guy is a seriously prolific actor and has played just about every part under the sun.

But purple isn't a good sign for him.

> Not sure about it not being a good sign, but his favorite color is purple and often requests props of this color. Of particular note is Mace Windu of Star Wars, who wields a purple lightsaber.

he's the shepherd of us all, from weaks to heroes,

> Shepherd refers to the infamous monologue from Pulp Fiction where he quotes Ezekiel 25:17 and ends with, "I’m tryin’ real hard to be the shepherd." From weak[ling]s to heroes possibly refers to his part in Unbreakable where he plays the fragile villain Mr. Glass opposite Bruce Willis's hero character.

Even if he is just a detestable servant.

> Likely a reference to his character in Django Unchained.

Comment: you got some a bit off but the general is here. Nice one

Answer (score 5):

> A Minion (specifically from dispicable me so that I can make sense of line 4)

You wouldn't call your friends the way he's called,

> Most people wouldn't call friends a minion.  I personally have but meh.

Yet you envy him in his lab.

> Minions work in an evil villain's laboratory.

He maybe had many various jobs,

> A minion can be called upon to do a great many things.

But purple isn't a good sign for him.

> Purple minions are crazy and dangerous.

he's the shepherd of us all, from weaks to heroes,

> I'm not sure about this one but maybe i should have watched the minion movie or something?

Even if he is just a detestable servant.

> A minion!

Comment: Hey, not bad but not what I had in mind :) the guy i'm looking for exists for real !

Comment: And you're calling him detestable?  A bit harsh maybe? :)

Answer (score 3):

> Dick Van Dyke

You wouldn't call your friends the way he's called,

> Two of his names are slurs.

Yet you envy him in his lab.

> Stared in Diagnosis Murder.

He maybe had many various jobs,

> His characters have had multiple jobs (but which actor hasn't?)

But purple isn't a good sign for him.

> In an episode of the Dick Van Dyke show, called "Pink Pills and Purple Parents" things go very wrong for Dick's character

He's the shepherd of us all, from weaks to heroes,

> He plays "Max **Sheppard**" in Found Money (TV Movie)

Even if he is just a detestable servant.

> Dick Van Dyke plays an eccentric philanthropist's thieving servant in Fitzwilly

I haven't seen any of the specific shows/movies above by the way, and I would point out that this question could be a little too broad given that I was able to IMDB the first actor with a slur in his name that popped into my head and find something to fit each line.  I expect that this could be true of a lot of famous actors and there could well be a better fit.  Also, personally I would have called out (or at least insinuated) that the answer was an actor in the title or body of the riddle.

Comment: Another good try but that's not it ! i'm adding some hints